# Multiple user login in Mac OS X

Tags: virtualization, mac-osx, virtual-machines, mac-osx-server

Remember how we setup Windows Server instances to which multiple developers can login and work simultaneously?

Is the same thing possible with Mac OS x/Server?

We are basically trying to setup a iPhone development team and need some cost effective solution (buying separate Mac Book Pro/ Mac Pro is the last option imho.)

Is it possible to virtualize Mac OS X legally? I know 10.6.x can be run by hacking VMware and coaxing it... but that won't dwell so well in an enterprise.

Regards,
Karan Misra

Comment: So you want your devs to be able to remote desktop *something* OSX based to use xcode?  I don't know.  This sounds like it won't scale very well.  Have you considered separate machines for each dev and using an svn repository instead?

Answer (score 2):

[AquaConnect](http://www.aquaconnect.net/) offers a terminal server for OS X Server that should do everything you want.  They also offer a free trial so you can see for yourself.  CodeRebel also offers the [iRAPP](http://www.coderebel.com/products/irapp-terminal-server/) terminal server with a similar trial.  Not sure which is better, but I plan on evaluating both before the year's end.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing like Terminal Service on Mac OS X so you can't remote connect more than 1 user at the same time.
Regarding virtualization, since Mac OS X server 10.5 you can legally virtualize Mac OS X server on top of Mac OS X server with tool such as [Parallels](http://www.parallels.com/fr/products/desktop/) or [VMWare](http://www.vmware.com/products/fusion/)

Comment: Ouch, I was afraid of that... 

However, some Googling has turned up the name Vine Server couple of times. I am trying to figure out if it is a viable option.

I wonder what the 'unlimited clients' means when Apple advertises Mac OS X Server.

Comment: That simply means that you can connect any number of AFP/SMB clients to the file server (or any other of the services offered by MacOS Server). With Windows Server you will need client access licenes for everything (and then again for access to terminal services).

Comment: "Unlimited clients" is a reference to how many users can connect to that server, alluding to the idea of CALs for device/user connections in Windows.

Comment: See my answer.  There is no terminal service functionality built into OS X Server, but you can accomplish it with 3rd party software.  Anyone who has managed OS X Server would advise against setting up multiple VMs for software development purposes.

Comment: Hmmm I manage OS X Server and I *wouldn't* advise against it. That's why I suggested it. I would suggest a lot of thought and testing, but then that holds true for any problem and solution that are not trivial.

There are pros and cons to both approaches.

Comment: In a datacenter environment, sure, OS X Server VMs can be a good idea.  On users' laptops & desktops... not so much.  Things like static IPs, DNS records & reservations, and all the other little quirks that make OS X Server what it is would not be easy to deploy & maintain on multiple end users' desktops & laptops.

Answer (score 0):

You mention OSX Server. I believe it's both possible and legal to virtualise that on physical Mac hardware (I wouldn't want to do it on anything other than a xserve or possibly a mac pro though).

I can't speak to the licence position (e.g. whether or not you need once licence per guest) but I know it's both possible and supported. You'd need virtualisation software too, either the vmware or parallels solution, I guess.